# Differencing to reduce frequency

Tags: r, time-series, apply, diff, frequency

I have several monthly time series stored in a file I want to difference with lag = 2 using R to get them quarterly, i.e. with 3 months being equal to one quarter, I want to difference between the third and first month. This shall leave me with one observation per quarter instead of three. Yet the apply function I wrote does not do what I want.

My data:

```
Time      TimeSeries_1 TimeSeries2
1980-01     200           1200
1980-02     300           1300
1980-03     400           1400
1980-04     500           1500
1980-05     600           1600
1980-06     700           1700
.
.
1980-12     1300          2700
```

My function:

```
data_diff = apply(data, MARGIN = 1, function(x) diff(x, lag = 2))
```

What I wanna get:

```
1980-Q1  200 (=400-200)
1980-Q2  200 (=700-50)
1980-Q3   ...
1980-Q4   ...
```

The dimension of the data frame do not change and I dont get why this transformation does not work. Thank you a lot!

PS Using `sapply()` instead, without any MARGIN argument also does not work.

Comment: Could you try this: `data_diff = apply(df[,-1], MARGIN = 2, function(x) diff(x, lag = 2))`

Comment: Thank you for the response! I guess `df[,-1],` shall remove the  time index column? I did this already, sry didnt say. I also did not transform it into a ts or xts object  etc.For MARGIN I read that 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns. As I want rowwise differencing for all of my 20 columns I set it to 1. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

in base R you will do:

```
dat$Time <- as.Date(sprintf("%s-01", dat$Time))
group <- interaction(quarters(dat$Time), format(dat$Time, "%Y"))
data.frame(lapply(dat[-1], function(x)  tapply(x, group, diff, lag = 2)))

        TimeSeries1 TimeSeries2
Q1.1980         200         200
Q2.1980         200         200
Q3.1980         200         200
Q4.1980         200         200
```

Comment: thanks! and if my data would be in the following format: 2000M01, 2000M02? I tried `"%M01"` but didnt work

Comment: @HPMinsky next time ensure you give your data the way you have it. so in your transformation, you should do `as.Date(sprintf("%s-01", dat$Time), format = "%YM%m-%d")`

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to add a log together with diff, ie to get diff(log(x)). `tapply(x, group, diff, lag = 2)))`but this did not work. any hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly verbose `tidyverse` approach, but it should return all variables correctly named for each quarter, given that there are no gaps.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~Time, ~ TimeSeries1, ~TimeSeries2,
               "1980-01",     100,           1000,
               "1980-02",     300,           1300,
               "1980-03",     400,           1300,
               "1980-04",     500,           1500,
               "1980-05",     600,           1600,
               "1980-06",     900,           1700,
               "1980-07",     200,           1200,
               "1980-08",     300,           1300,
               "1980-09",     750,           1400,
               "1980-10",     500,           1500,
               "1980-11",     600,           1600,
               "1980-12",     700,           1700)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Time = paste0(gsub("[0-9]{2}$", "", Time),
                          quarters(as.Date(paste0(Time, "-01"))))
         ) %>% 
  nest_by(Time) %>% 
  mutate(data = summarise(data, across(everything(), 
                                    ~ diff(.x, lag = 2)))) %>% 
  unpack(data)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Time    TimeSeries1 TimeSeries2
#>   <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 1980-Q1         300         300
#> 2 1980-Q2         400         200
#> 3 1980-Q3         550         200
#> 4 1980-Q4         200         200
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>